# Linearly constrained eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Suppose I'd like to:

\begin{align}
\mathop{\text{min}}_\mathbf{x} && \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \\
\text{subject to:} && \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x} = 1\\
&& \mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}
\end{align}
where all vector variables are known except $\mathbf{x}$, and $\mathbf{C}$ is full row rank.

If I didn't have the $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ constraint then after applying the Lagrange multiplier method I could solve this as a generalized eigenvalue problem:

\begin{align}
\text{solve} && \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x}\\
\text{subject to:} && \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x} = 1\\
\end{align}

If I try to apply the same approach to my original problem I get something that doesn't look quite like a generalized Eigenvalue problem:

\begin{align}
\text{solve} &&
\left(\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{C}^T\\
\mathbf{C} & \mathbf{0}
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{x} &\\
\mu
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix} 
\lambda \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{b}
\end{matrix}\right)\\
\text{subject to:} && \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x} = 1 \\
\end{align}

*Ideally*, I'd like to reduce my problem to an instance of the generalized eigenvalue problem so I can use an off-the-shelf numerical solver.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

(The title of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29958/eigenvalue-problems-with-linear-constraints) is the same, but I couldn't parse the actual question to verify duplicity).

Comment: I am fairly certain this problem can be quite challenging.  Check out the "LSQI" section of Golub+Van Loan or this reference:  http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379589904941/1-s2.0-0024379589904941-main.pdf?_tid=9a4f8a7c-984e-11e5-a350-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1448990087_94e70d32962d0802a112ed968f8d4e9a

Comment: Some relevant slides:  http://www2.cs.cas.cz/harrachov/slides/Golub.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think Pushpendre's answer isn't quite right, but it gets you most of the way there.  Getting rid of that pesky constant term is a bit tricky relative to the homogeneous case.

Let's take his suggested substitutions:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
M&:=N^\top N\\
y&:=Nx\\
D&:=CN^{-1}\\
B&:=N^{-\top}AN^{-1}
\end{array}
$$
I don't think these are strictly necessary (e.g. this encodes an assumption that $M$ is semidefinite), but it simplifies notation quite a bit for the most realistic/common case.  I'm going to be cavalier about assuming certain matrices are symmetric/invertible as convenient.

Then, your problem becomes
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min_y &y^\top By\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & \|y\|^2=1\\
& Dy=b
\end{array}
$$
This problem has Lagrange multiplier expression (I am sprinkling in constant factors so that they simplify my arithmetic later)
$$
\Lambda(y;\lambda,\mu):=\frac{1}{2}y^\top By+\frac{1}{2}\lambda(1-\|y\|^2)+\mu^\top (b-Dy)
$$
Differentiating with respect to $y$ shows
$$
0=\nabla_y\Lambda(y;\lambda,\mu)=By-\lambda y-D^\top\mu.
$$
Here I am assuming w.l.o.g. that $B$ is symmetric.

Pre-multiplying the critical point condition by $D$ shows
$$
DBy=\lambda Dy + DD^\top\mu=\lambda b + DD^\top \mu.
$$
Let's further assume that $D$ has full rank.  The most common case is that $D\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},$ where $m<n$; I'll assume $D$ has rank $m$.  Then, $DD^\top$ is an invertible matrix, and $D$ admits a pseudoinverse $D^+:=D^\top (DD^\top)^{-1}$ satisfying $DD^+=I$.

Then, we can isolate $\mu$ as
$$
\mu=(DD^\top)^{-1}(DBy-\lambda b).
$$
Plugging this back into the expression for $\nabla_y\Lambda$ shows
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
0&=By-\lambda y-D^\top (DD^\top)^{-1}(DBy-\lambda b)\\
&=By-\lambda y-D^+(DBy-\lambda b)\\
\implies [(I-D^+D)B-\lambda I]y&=-\lambda D^+b.
\end{array}
$$
For each $\lambda$, this expression gives a system of equation solvable for $y$.  In other words, we can think of $y$ as a **function** $y(\lambda)$ of $\lambda$.

Define a function $f(\lambda):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ as $$f(\lambda):=\|y(\lambda)\|^2-1.$$  Use any standard 1d method to find a root $\lambda$ such that $f(\lambda)=0.$  Then, $y(\lambda)$ is a critical point of your optimization problem.  To be totally rigorous, you should check that $y(\lambda)$ satisfies the constraint $Dy=b$, but this is easy to check for *any* $\lambda$ from the system for $y(\lambda)$ (multiply both sides by $D$).

Note that numerically the problem of finding roots of $f(\cdot)$ isn't great.  $f$ likely has multiple roots and asymptotes where the system of equations for $y$ is not solvable.  It is known as a *secular equation,* for which some specialized solution algorithms exist.

---

**NOTE:**  This trick is similar to the one suggested for "LSQI" in Golub/Van Loan's book.

Comment: Note this assumes $b\neq0$.  When $b=0$ a much easier approach is to use an augmented generalized eigenvalue problem.

Comment: What about $ \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} $ subject to $ {x}^{T} x \leq 1 $?

Comment: @Royi, this is a convex problem --- interior point methods and the like would solve it.  Alternatively, you could test two cases --- either $x^\top x < 1$, in which case $A^\top A x = A^\top b$, or $x^\top x = 1$, in which case you can use the method above or something simpler since you do not have a linear constraint.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem has been answered at 
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14096/sparse-smallest-eigenvalue-problem-on-a-linear-subspace :) Or you can read Golub's original paper [Some modified matrix eigenvalue problems](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/309f10/modified.pdf)

The basic intuition is that basically you want to find the eigenvalues over a subspace that is defined $Cx = b$ so just find its basis and convert the rayleigh quotient to that basis.

EDIT: I just realized that you need the space which satisfies $Cx=b$ and zero need not be in this space so its not a subspace. But I think the techniques in those answers could still be adapted.

WRONG <strike>One way I can think of handling the nonzero right hand size is to make an augmented matrix $C'=[C\; b]$ and augmented $x' = [x; 1]$ then $C'x' = 0$ and then also create $M' = [M\; 0; 0\; 0]$ and same for $A$. After this augmentation and zero padding everything works out.</strike>

2nd try: we can re write the objective as $$\arg \min \frac{X^TAX}{X^TMx} \textrm{subject to } C(x-x')=0$$ where $x'$ is any point satisfying $Cx=b$ and then assuming that $M$ is positve definite which means that it can be broken into $M = N^TN$ (assuming real.)

let $y = Nx$.

let $B = (N^{-1})^TAN^{-1}$.

let $D = CN^{-1}$.

then the objective becomes $$\arg\min \frac{y^TBy}{y^Ty} \textrm{ subject to } D(y-y') = 0$$. Now we are pretty close to  Golub's setup in 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 but not quite because of the non-zero RHS. But we can still use the lagrangian (assuming everywhere things were positive definite and inverses were well conditioned (practically))

So the lagrangian is 
$$y^TBy - \lambda (y^Ty -1) + 2 \mu^T(D(y-y'))$$

**EDIT: See Justin's answer above for a correct explanation**

<strike>The first derivative is 
$$By - \lambda y + 2 \mu^TD = 0$$
multiply with $D^T$ on the right and use the constraint that $D^Ty = D^Ty'$ to get
$$By'B^T - \lambda y'B^T + 2 \mu^T DD^T = 0$$
which gives us a value of $\mu$ (because we know $B$ and $y'$ and I assume that since $C$ was full row rank therefore $DD^T$ would be invertible, if not invertible then we have a range of solutions for $\mu$ and would have to pick the best) then substitute to get a generalized eigen value problem in terms of lambda which would be the solution.</strike>

Comment: in your EDIT you mean $Cx = b$, right?

Comment: Also, the non-zero right-hand side is the _real_ issue here. I'm not convinced one can trivial apply subspace methods in this case.

Comment: yes, the edit meant $cx=b$. also I added a way to handle non zero rhs

Comment: Won't it be problematic that $A'$ and $M'$ are now singular?

Comment: ah yes, it would be a problem. Editing again

Comment: I'm only missing how we know the value of $\mu$ from the last equation.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, $y'$ and $B$ are known and I implicitly assumed $DD^T$ was invertible. We know $y'$ because it is the image of $x'$ (we chose if to be any point satisfying $Cx=b$.) Also since $D = CN^{-1}$ where $C$ is full row rank means $DD^T = C N^{-1}N^{-T} C^T$ which I think we can prove by the SVD of $C$ that its going to be non-singular. Of course numerically it might be ill conditioned so you'd want to regularize somehow. If $DD^T$ still turns out to be singular then basically you have a whole subspace for $\mu$ and you'll have to be careful to prune out the false-optima !

Comment: Also I edited the last equation to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm afraid some equations here don't make sense, e.g. the product "$By'B^T$" doesn't work out dimension-wise.

Comment: @Justin Yes you are right. Actually, looking back at it now I was too hasty in writing my solution and even my gradient is wrong, there is a factor of two missing and I should have taken the transpose of $\mu^TD$ !! Thanks for pointing it out.